# How to get web api url inside controller and save in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this API project for employee details. How do I get the API URL something like this "http://localhost:53037/api/employee/4" inside the Home controller and to save that URL into the database?

Employee Controller :

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
    {
        using(EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            return entities.Employees.ToList();
        }
    }

    public Employee Get(int id)
    {
        using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            return entities.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
    public void Post([FromBody] Employee employee)
    {
        using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            entities.Employees.Add(employee);
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Home Controller :

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly MyDBEntities _db = new MyDBEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
```

}

Comment: Have you tried sending the url from your View to your Controller and then saving that?

Comment: No. how do I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to save this URL into the database? What's the purpose?

Comment: to track which api has been accessed by the user

Comment: From my experience with Razor Views you can call your Controller from your View (cshtml documents) with `@Html.Action("{method name}", {value})`. Obviously remove the curly braces.  Basically how you would normally submit form data in your view via HTML/Javascript use this code and make the value the input from the user.

Comment: @Nav That should probably be handled with an action filter that just logs when the user accesses a page, you can grab the current URL from the HttpContext. You can then apply that action filter to whatever action methods you want, or to all action methods by registering it as a global filter. I suggest you read up on ASP.NET MVC and Web API Action Filters.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is to use the proper attributes

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/employee/{id}/")]
    public Employee Get([FromRoute]int id)
    {
        using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            return entities.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Not sure if i understood that question correctly, but if you are trying to get an employee from the database by id, that's the way to go. Everything concerning your employees should happen through the EmployeeController.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to get the api path  or api url "http://localhost:53037/api/employee/4"

Comment: What about `var url = "localhost:53037/api/employee/4";` ? (and by this you should realize that your question is far too vague to answer)

Comment: Everytime somebody uses that url, the `Get(int id)` method from the `EmployeeController` will be called. Perhaps you could save the url from there?